# Azure DevOps user present in AAD but user disconnected

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I manage an Azure DevOps org. There is a user who is no longer an active employee. Their account is still in Azure Active Directory, but now, DevOps is reporting that "organization can't sign in because they're not in the ... Azure Active Directory. Delete any unwanted users in Organization settings, and then Resolve for remaining members." I confirmed the user still exists in Azure AD, though "Block sign-in" is set to "Yes." I do not have any "Group Rules" configured in DevOps.

When I click Resolve and search for the user in the "Matched Identity in Directory" box, I find the user and click on it. When I then click on Next, I get the error message "1 organization member(s) failed to get mapped. Continue resolving disconnected members by inviting them to the Azure Active Directory or retry failed mappings later." I click on the details link, and the message states "Cannot transfer identity to itself." I would prefer not to delete this user since there is work item and check-in history. Does anyone have any recommendations for resolving this issue?

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear - are you saying that you want the user to be able to log in to Azure DevOps? Or someone else who's active cannot?

Comment: The person who owned the account no longer works for my org. On the users screen, I am presented with the above error messages, and I am trying to resolve them. The account will not be logged into in the future, but is associated with old work items and checkins, so I don't want to simply delete the account and lose the history. I don't understand why this is an error to begin with, since the user's account is still present in Azure AD, and we have other users in DevOps that are no longer with the org without this error occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the default behavior that users that are removed from AAD or being blocked sign-in will fail to get mapped in Azure devops.

To get rid of the warning, you can remove the blocked user from azure devops organization(or from AAD). There is no need to worry about the losing of history. For it is described as below in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/delete-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page).

> After you remove a user from Azure AD, you can't assign artifacts to that user anymore. Examples are work items and pull requests. However, we preserve the history of artifacts that were already assigned to the user.

However, you also just ignore the warning message and keep the user in your azure devops organization.

Comment: I thought that removing a user broke history. Glad to see that it didn't. I removed the user from the org and the message is gone. Thanks for the help!